# are dynamic strings possible in zig?

Tags: string, unicode, zig

I'm just getting started with Zig and come from C++ and Rust;

I've been struck early with a difficult issue that I cannot seem to solve. Or find anywhere on the internet.

**This is what I have:**

```
// this doesn't work
pub const User = struct {

  bot:       bool,
  id:        *const [*:0]u8,
  username:  *const [*:0]u8,

  pub fn init() User {
  
    return User {

      .bot      = false,
      .id       = "THIS_IS_ID",
      .username = "THIS_IS_USERNAME"
    
    };
  }

  ...

}

const user = User.init();


// this works vvv
id: *const [10:0]u8,
.id = "THIS_IS_ID",
```

**This is the error I get:**

```bash
error: expected type '*const [*:0]u8', found '*const [10:0]u8'
  .id = "THIS_IS_ID",
```

My objective that I'm trying to get out of asking this question is to know if it's possible to have dynamic strings in zig; and if so, how so? I've seen some custom String structs online but was wondering if there is a way to achieve this without creating a separate type / struct for it..?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Use `[]const u8` or `[]u8`. See documentation for [slices](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Slices).

What `const` changes:

```
// Can assign string literals
var id: []const u8 = "THIS_IS_ID";
// vs
// var id: []u8 = "THIS_IS_ID";
//                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
// error: expected type '[]u8', found '*const [10:0]u8'
// note: cast discards const qualifier

// But cannot change individual bytes
std.mem.copy(u8, id, "THIS_IS_ANOTHER_ID");
//               ^~
// error: expected type '[]u8', found '[]const u8'
// note: cast discards const qualifier
```

You'd have to decide what owns the memory:

- It could be each individual variable, or a field.
- Or a separate memory buffer, or an [allocator](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Memory).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know too much about the problem scope (or zig either), but here's what I think you need to do:

- for dynamic string (allocation) in zig, you need to ensure that you have an allocator to allocate some memory for the string.

```
// you can use any allocator you prefer
const allocator = std.heap.page_allocator;
```

- you then need to actually allocate some space for the string you want to store

```
// here we allocate some memory for the string we want to store
// we allocate some memory for 10 bytes (which can store
// a string having at most 10 characters)
// NOTE: the operation could fail, hence the `try`
var slice = try allocator.alloc(u8, 10);
```

- and finally, write the string you want to store into the allocated buffer/slice

```
// we write the string we want to store into the slice (or
// buffer) we previously allocated above
// NOTE: the operation could fail, hence the `try`. Also,
//       the function returns a slice of the buffer printed to.
_ = try std.fmt.bufPrint(slice, "hello", .{});

// you can print out the contents of the slice (or buffer)
std.debug.print("{s}", .{slice});
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted before, it looks like you want immutable `.id` and `.username` strings. In that case you can do:

```
struct {
    id: []const u8,
    username: []const u8,
```

… instead of:

```
struct {
    id: *const [*:0]u8,
    username: *const [*:0]u8,
```

… and then you can assign them to literals like `.id = "THIS_IS_ID".

If you do want mutable strings, then use `dupe` from `std.mem.Allocator` as follows.

```
    const id = try allocator.dupe(u8, "THIS_IS_ID");
    errdefer allocator.free(id);
    const username = try allocator.dupe(u8, "THIS_IS_USERNAME");
    return User {
      .bot      = false,
      .id       = id,
      .username = username,
    };
```

Zig forces you to explicitly take ownership of the new memory this way.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example of me creating dynamic files names from an dynamic input source that contains the string of the name of the file to be created.

```rust
pub fn render(allocator: std.mem.Allocator, registry: ag.CoreRegistry) !void {
    const filepath = try std.fmt.allocPrint(
        allocator,
        "src/codegen/abi/bindings/bytecode/{s}",
        .{registry.magic_number},
    );
    defer allocator.free(filepath);

    const file = try std.fs.cwd().createFile(
        filepath,
        .{ .read = true },
    );
    defer file.close();
    try render_abi_bytecode_bindings(file, allocator, registry.contract_abi);
}
```